# ASP.NET MVC 4 JS Minification Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using [google-code-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.  It works in debug mode but in release the minification/bundling step fails.

I get this error:

> "Minification failed. Returning unminified contents. (104,399-436):
>   run-time error JS5017: Syntax error in regular expression:
>   /^(?:\r\n|[\S\s])[^\n\r#*=A-[^`h{~]*/"

The file it's complaining about is: [lang-wiki.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-wiki.js)

This is the latest version from google and it runs in debug so I can only assume the bundling is incorrectly parsing the regular expression.

Other than omitting this file what else can I do?  Ideally I would like to disable any error checking the bundling step attempts.

I'm using these versions:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3

I tried minifying these files with [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) and it works so that seems to support the incorrect parsing theory.

Answer (score 0):

Some of minification tools such as google closure or YUI have different behavior on considering semi-colons and this cause some problems when a script is not well-formatted, while if you use *grease* or *ajax-minifer* which are tools from *Microsoft*, you won't see these type of problems.

**[Ajax-Minifer](https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/)** also has build scripts that may help you out performing some actions during build process as required.